# PostgreSQL Trigger and Function populating too many columns

Tags: function, postgresql, triggers, schema, plpgsql

I'm managing a reminder messaging DB for a large email marketer. We send out daily reminders for users to perform a function that is prize related. Part of the analytics requirements that I've set for tracking acquisition and attrition require I set a date when users subscribe and unsubscribe. I have a PostgreSQL trigger that I'm using to fire a proc to update a dateunsub and datejoined column for each optin.

My table schema looks like this:

[image]

The opt-ins themselves (optinX_unsub) are either 'Y', 'N', or NULL (Yes meaning the user wishes to no longer receive the messaging, No meaning they wish to receive the messaging).

OptinX_datejoined should be set to now() when an optin goes from either NULL to 'N' or from 'Y' to 'N' (meaning they were subscribed previously but unsubscribed, but now are wanting back in). OptinX_dateunsub should be set to now() when a subscription goes from 'N' to 'Y' (again meaning they no longer want the mailings).

Created_on gets set to now() when the record is initially inserted and it never changes. Last_modified gets set to now() anytime an TG_OP = 'UPDATE' (when an update occurs on the table).

Here's my trigger:

```
    CREATE TRIGGER upd_optins_trigger BEFORE UPDATE ON 
tablename FOR EACH ROW 
EXECUTE PROCEDURE proc_upd()
```

And here's my function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.proc_upd()
RETURNS trigger
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
BEGIN
  IF (NEW.optin1_unsub = 'Y') THEN
       NEW.optin1_dateunsub := now();
  ELSIF (NEW.optin1_unsub = 'N' ) THEN
       NEW.optin1_datejoined := now();
  END IF;

  IF (NEW.optin2_unsub = 'Y') THEN
       NEW.optin2_dateunsub := now();
  ELSIF (NEW.optin2_unsub = 'N') THEN
       NEW.optin2_datejoined := now();
  END IF;

  IF (NEW.optin3_unsub = 'Y') THEN
       NEW.optin3_dateunsub := now();
  ELSIF (NEW.optin3_unsub = 'N' ) THEN
       NEW.optin3_datejoined := now();
  END IF;

  IF (NEW.optin4_unsub = 'Y') THEN
       NEW.optin4_dateunsub := now();
  ELSIF (NEW.optin4_unsub = 'N' ) THEN
       NEW.optin4_datejoined := now();
  END IF;

  IF (NEW.optin5_unsub = 'Y') THEN
       NEW.optin5_dateunsub := now();
  ELSIF (NEW.optin5_unsub = 'N' ) THEN
       NEW.optin5_datejoined := now();
  END IF;

  IF (NEW.optin6_unsub = 'Y') THEN
       NEW.optin6_dateunsub := now();
  ELSIF (NEW.optin6_unsub = 'N' ) THEN
       NEW.optin6_datejoined := now();
  END IF;


  NEW.last_modified := now();
  RETURN NEW;

END;

$function$
```

Now here's my issue. I have an application that's pulling the numbers down daily via CRON using this query for each opt-in, and passing it into a reporting API:

```
select
count (*) as tablename_total,
(
select
count (*)
from
tablename
where
  optin1_dateunsub = '2014-04-22') as optin1_unsub_yesterday,
  (
select
  count (*)
from
  tablename
where
  optin1_dateunsub between date_trunc('month',
  current_date) and
  '2014-04-22') as optin1_unsub_this_month,
  (
select
  count (*)
from
  tablename
where
  optin1_unsub = 'N' and
  (emailaddress_status = 'VALID' or
  emailaddress_status is null)) as optin1_reminder_total,
  (
select
  count (*)
from
  tablename
where
optin1_unsub = 'N' and
(emailaddress_status = 'VALID' or
emailaddress_status is null) and
optin1_datejoined = '2014-04-22') as optin1_reminder_yesterday,
...
```

Here's what the numbers look like after the fact.

[image]

The only "events" going on right now that users would be interested in receiving an email about is associated to optin2, optin5, or optin6 - Optin2 being the largest and most promoted so the 14,903 new subscriptions to optin2 is as expected. The event that's associated with optin1 is long over, so 11k new subscribers and 1k lost subscribers to that list is strange. Same goes for the optin3, that event is not for another couple of months so for us to have lost 5,258 subscriptions when we're not mailing to those subscribers seems like an issue with my trigger and function. We don't routinely lose that many subscribers daily when we're mailing to them.

Sorry for the long-windedness, just trying to be thorough. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You really should rethink your schema here,  you really shouldn't be repeating columns like that.  That will greatly simplify your trigger as well.

Comment: I think I've narrowed it down to new.* portion. This should be old.*.

Comment: email marketer .. brrr.

Comment: I can think of worse. When done ethically (meaning when the subscribers wishes are honored at all times - immediately when requested - and if the marketer never mails to anyone unless explicitly indicated) it's a very valuable marketing channel. I could be stealing cars or clubbing baby seals...